# How to measure SW API?

Tags: software-design

I know how to measure module implementation using LOC, SLOC or any other metrics.

But I would like to know: is it possible to "measure" several different APIs in order to find "the best one"?

For example:
Nucleus RTOS:
STATUS NU_Create_Semaphore(NU_SEMAPHORE *semaphore, CHAR *name, UNSIGNED initial_count, OPTION suspend_type);

Posix: int sem_init(sem_t *sem, int pshared, unsigned int value);

For example we can state that creation of semaphore in Nucleus OS shall use more stack than Posix variant. So can we conclude that in this case Posix is better API if we use "size of stack" as "measure"?

Or this analysis is just stupid?

And if above is not stupid then I am wondering more: it is "easy" to measure API which cover same functions (create sempahore, create threads etc) but how to measure APIs which provide same functionality where functions are not "equal"?

I can imagine test which will have same functionality made using different API.
After comparing several such created tests by different metrics (memory consumption, LOC, SLOC etc) can I conclude that one API is better then other?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

1. Find the API that provides you with the capabilities / functions you need
2. From those, use the ones that are the simplest.

Long term, simplicity and maintainability are *far* more important than performance, especially if this API is not from an app-local library but a remote service.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I do not need "programmer" solution to problem. Is there "scientific" solution to such problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "scientific". The only reason I can see for looking at different APIs is to decide which one to use for a project. Given that you didn't provide any sort of metric by which to measure "better", what is the purpose of the exercise and what sort of an answer are you looking for?

Comment: I think the solution is scientific. If you want fancy names you can call the step 2 - Apply the Occam's razor principle.

Comment: [Science](http://xkcd.com/683/) can mean [different things](http://xkcd.com/701/) to [different people](http://xkcd.com/242/)...

Comment: @darlinton - Step 1 could also be called "Data collection phase" if we are looking for more pointless but impressive sounding terms.

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on your Judging criteria.
best option is to list out all the available API's for your required functionality
fix up a judging criteria, which can be based on your requirement
it can be time complexity (order of function),Space Complexity, ease of Use, Your understanding of API, Re usability in other modules or whatever is your application requirement and based on it make a judgement.